# Injective type families with GADTs

Tags: haskell, ghc

I tried a very simple example involving injective type families, but I can't get it to work.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilyDependencies #-}

type family F c = result | result -> c

data G b where
  G :: G b -> G (F b)

foo :: G (F a) -> G a
foo (G a) = a
```

This results in a compile error

```
Inject.hs:10:13: error:
    • Could not deduce: b ~ a
      from the context: F a ~ F b
        bound by a pattern with constructor: G :: forall b. G b -> G (F b),
                 in an equation for ‘foo’
        at Inject.hs:10:6-8
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a pattern with constructor: G :: forall b. G b -> G (F b),
        in an equation for ‘foo’
        at Inject.hs:10:6
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          foo :: forall a. G (F a) -> G a
        at Inject.hs:9:8
      Expected type: G a
        Actual type: G b
    • In the expression: a
      In an equation for ‘foo’: foo (G a) = a
    • Relevant bindings include
        a :: G b (bound at Inject.hs:10:8)
        foo :: G (F a) -> G a (bound at Inject.hs:10:1)
```

which is the same error I get if I use a non-injective/ordinary type family for `F`. What gives?

Comment: This seems to be a case of https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10833

Comment: At the moment injective type families are not very useful IMO. Injectivity only allows to express some types which would be ambiguous (see the GHC docs) but nothing more. One surely would expect the above to compile.

Comment: Thanks kosmikus. chi: I sure expected it to compile! That's a pretty worthless "feature"...